# How can I draws the solid as a framework and sets up dashed lines for the hidden edges in pst-solides3d?

Tags: pst-solides3d

I tried

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-2.5,-2)(2.5,2.5)
\psset{lightsrc=10 20 30,viewpoint=30 10 30 rtp2xyz,Decran=40}
 \psSolid[object=icosahedron,a=3,linecolor=blue,
          opacity=0.6,hollow,hue=0 1,          action=draw]
 %\axesIIID(3,3,3)(6,4,4)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remove  `opacity=0.6,hollow,hue=0 1`, then I get hidden lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}(-2.5,-2)(2.5,2.5)
        \psset{lightsrc=10 20 30,viewpoint=30 10 30 rtp2xyz,Decran=40}
        \psSolid[object=icosahedron,a=3,linecolor=blue,
        action=draw]
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\begin{document}
\multido{\iA=0+5}{50}{%
    \psset{viewpoint=50 -45 \iA\space add 30 rtp2xyz,Decran=50}
    \begin{pspicture}[solidmemory](-4,-4)(4,4)
        \psSolid[object=icosahedron,a=2.5,action=draw,linecolor=blue]
    \end{pspicture}%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]